# Formik FieldArray textfield input only allows one character before losing focus

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have the following component and don't understand why my `<TextField>` entry loses focus just after entering one character.

I have placed the `key={index}` where I assume it needs it.

If anyone can see what I am missing to cause this textfield losing focus, that would be great.

```
const MyValues = ({ myGroup, name, myIndex }) => (
    <FieldArray
      name={name}
      render={(arrayHelpers) => (      
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.dataSourceLayout} key={myIndex}>
                {myGroup.myValues.map((myValue, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Grid 
                      container 
                      item  
                      key={index} 
                      spacing={6}>
                <Grid
                    item
                    container
                    spacing={1}
                >         
                    <Grid item xs={5}>
                        <Select
                            name={`${name}.${index}.job`}
                            label='Job'
                            options={jobs}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                     <Grid item xs={5}>
                        <TextField
                            name={`${name}.${index}.salary`}
                            label='Salary'
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={2}>
                        {myGroup.myValues.length > 1 && (
                            <Button                                
                                disableElevation
                                onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                                >
                                <span>Delete</span>
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    </Grid>                    
                </Grid>
                </Grid>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            </React.Fragment>
      )} 
    />           
  );
```

Comment: can you create working example like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/formik/formik/tree/master/examples/field-arrays?from-embed) with dummy data

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to put parentheses around index on the fields name

```
<Select
  name={`${name}.[${index}].job`}
  label='Job'
  options={jobs}
/>
```